# adding label controls to Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I want to display multiple formatting text into one datagrid cell. For this i thought of using Label controls into the datagrid cell. The datagrid is data-sourced from sqlite connection. 
How can i achieve this goal? can anyone suggest me of using Label controls into the datagrid to accomplish this target.

Answer (score 0):

first opportunity is to add a label to a DataGridTextBoxColumn using a DataGridTableStyle
an example could be found here :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vasanthks/how-to-add-label-controls-in-datagrid/

If this don't fit for your needs you can derive from DataGridViewCell and override the Paint methods. With this solution you are totally free in the way you present the texts.
But it is more work.